# How can I insert a character in the middle of a string in SQLite

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, sql-update, substring

I have a column in my DB with some numbers with the following format:

```
15020
13000
5000
7070
125355
1850000
```

and I need to update the column values, inserting a ',' before the last two digits. I expect the outcome to be like this:

```
150,20
130,00
50,00
70,70
1253,55
18500,00
```

I have tried this:

```
UPDATE table
SET [column] = replace([column],substr([column],-2),','||substr([column],-2));
```

but it is not working as I expected, this is what I get in return:

```
150,20
13,000
5,000
,70,70
1253,55
185,0000
```

Any help would be apreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function [`SUBSTR()`](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr).

You can get the part of the string before the last 2 chars with:

```
SUBSTR([column], 1, LENGTH([column]) -2)
```

and the last 2 chars with:

```
SUBSTR([column], -2)
```

So the update statement should be:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET [column] = SUBSTR([column], 1, LENGTH([column]) -2) || 
               ',' || 
               SUBSTR([column], -2);
```

If you have values with 1 or 2 digits and you want a leading `0` before `,` then:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET [column] = CASE WHEN LENGTH([column]) <= 2 THEN '0' ELSE '' END ||
               SUBSTR([column], 1, LENGTH([column]) -2) || 
               ',' || 
               SUBSTR([column], -2);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=42485bd4121c59dad43c94fbf972800f).

Another way to get the part of the string before the last 2 chars is with an implicit conversion to an integer by an integer division:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET [column] = ([column] / 100) || ',' || SUBSTR([column], -2);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=19473a86f20e04e36bdf608ee6f568bb).

Answer (score 1):

One method would use `printf()`:

```
select printf('%d,%02d', cast(col / 100 int), col % 100)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=18bfbd29b1bebb731d3afae739abc332) is a db<>fiddle.

In an update, this would simply be:

```
update t
    set column = select printf('%d,%02d', cast(column / 100 int), column % 100);
```